# Select all text across multiple stories

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I need to change all text in all the stories in an indd file from "Adobe Paragraph Composer" to "Adobe World-ready Paragraph Composer".

Can it be done through UI or I have to use scripts. In the latter case, how do you set scope to all stories and change the paragraph composer?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to select all stories at once with the UI.
You will have to iterate through all paragraphs in all textframes in all stories or the selected story. *Should be something like (not tested):*

**edit: remove textframes as suggested by Jongware**

```
for (var s = 0; app.documents[0].stories.length; s++) {
    for (var p = 0; p < app.documents[0].stories[s].paragraphs.length; p++) {
      app.documents[0].stories[s].paragraphs[p].composer = "Adobe World-ready Paragraph Composer";
  }
}
```

Comment: Gives error saying "Invalid value set for property 'composer'. Expected String, but received "Adobe World-ready Paragraph Composer".

Comment: Are you in a different language? Try setting a composer, then select some text and run this code `$.writeln(app.activeDocument.selection[0].paragraphs[0].composer)`

Comment: I'm on Win 7 using ExtendScript. When I execute this line from the inDesign's inbuilt script editor, the line is highlighted in orange and below it says 'undefined is not an object'.

Comment: Did you change the target  application ?  It's the drop down in the upper left corner

Comment: When I changed it to inDesign CS6 in the dropdown box it seemed to run but didn't change anything. The selected paragraph is still in "Adobe Paragraph composer"

Comment: When running which script? `$.writeln(app.activeDocument.selection[0].paragraphs[0].composer)` just gives an output into the console of ESTK.